# laravel broadcasting Broadcasting in private chanel not working i use laravel echo

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, pusher, laravel-echo, laravel-broadcast

event is:

```
public $chat ;
public function __construct($chat)
{
        $this->chat = $chat;
}
 public function broadcastOn()
{
    //        return new Channel('recieve-chat');
    return new PrivateChannel('recieve-chat' );
}
```

routes/channels.php is:

```
Broadcast::channel('recieve-chat', function ($user ) {
        return true;
//    return $user->id === $reciever_id;
});
```

in blade file:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' , function () {
         Echo.private('recieve-chat')
                .listen('ChatBroad', (e) => {
                    window.livewire.emit('recieve:' + e.chat.bid_id , e.chat);
                    $(chatScrollDown('.chat'+ e.chat.bid_id ));
                });
        });

</script>
```

broadcast Channel work properly. but in PrivateChannel is not working. and in console not showing any error

i use laravel echo and pusher

Comment: do you have 403 error on your console?

Comment: no any error in the console

Comment: @code-for-money i realized ;aravel echo cant subscribe to private channel automaticaly.

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: hey there, no i cant solve it.
and I explained all the problem in  the [github.com/laravel/echo/issues/302](https://github.com/laravel/echo/issues/302).
I will be grateful for your help @Doggo

Answer (score 0):

in App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    Broadcast::routes();

    require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
```

must like the code. in Broadcast::routes() we dont need any middleware.